# Using preprocessor variable as include file parameter in Progress

Tags: parameters, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to use `SCOPED-DEFINE` or `GLOBAL-DEFINE` preprocessor variable as named input parameter to my `.i` file.

**myprocedure.p:**

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE MYDATATYPE INTEGER

{myinclude.i &DATATYPE={&MYDATATYPE} }
```

**myinclude.i:**

```
DEF VAR data AS &DATATYPE NO-UNDO.
```

Does Progress support this type of functionality? I'd also like to be able to "forward" include parameters to another include file inside that include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

myprocedure.p:

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE MYDATATYPE INTEGER

{Training/PP/myinclude.i &DATATYPE={&MYDATATYPE}}
```

or

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE MYDATATYPE INTEGER

{Training/PP/myinclude.i &DATATYPE="{&MYDATATYPE}"}
```

and myinclude.i:

```
DEF VAR data AS {&DATATYPE} NO-UNDO.
```

You were missing the curly braces in the include file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-122/page/Argument-reference.html?labelkey=product_openedge_122) for the syntax of how to reference and pass arguments.